# Load JSON with IMG, SCRIPT, or LINK tags :: Security Questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, security

Let my page include something like **<IMG SRC="gmail.com/data.JSON">** (img, link, or script tag).

When you visit my page it will **load your emails** into my page.

**1. How do I access the content** (gmail.com/data.json) of IMG, LINK, or SCRIPT tag in javascript **?**

**2.** If the IMG loads a real image, from what I understand it can be copied to canvas, **can we copy the json text to canvas to have access to it ?**

*DISCLAIMER: I'm almost 100.00% sure it won't work, I want to know EVERY reason for why it won't work (browser security, etc), for the sake of KNAWLEDGE*

*(gmail/json begins with "while(1);" as a protection against loading it with SCRIPT tag, however it doesn't require any CSRF token -- aka. too expensive to implement at such a large scale; facebook uses "for(;;;)"*

Many thanks.

Comment: If you're going to DISLIKE, let me know why !!

Comment: Resource's content loaded cross domain through tags like script, link, video, audio, etc are not readable

Comment: @Patrick Evans Can you give me a source ? What about IMG tag ? it's data I think can be imported into cavas, the import to cavas is only same origin ? Why would google/facebook use 'while(1)" was script tag readable in older browsers ?

Comment: *cavas = canvas (I'm to dumb to type)